# Protractor throwing "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

My protractor tests pass just fine, but when it starts up I see an "undefined". I have no idea what this is in reference to or why it is appearing. help?

```
test@test-Gazelle:~/git/Protractor$ protractor conf.js
[21:35:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:35:46] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Started
undefined
...


3 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 12.422 seconds
```

This is the only reference to "console" in my code - 
(I'm new to protractor / Js (Jasmine), so I wouldn't understand why console will have an affect). BTW, this code is never executed.

```
var tools = require('./tools.js');

console.log(tools.hello());

var closure = tools.retreive();

console.log(closure());
```

Below is my conf.js file -

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,


    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            /*args: ['--window-size=800,1000']*/
        }
    },
    /*capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A300 Safari/602.1 AmericanAirlines']
        }
    },*/
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },
    /*
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName:'firefox'
        }, 
        {
            browserName:'chrome'
        }
     ],
     */

    /*specs: ['testScripts/changeResBackgroundColor.js', 'testScripts/paddingForContinueButton.js'],*/
    specs: ['testScripts/testFunctions.js'],
    framework: 'jasmine',

    onPrepare: function () {
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            savePath: './target/',
            filePrefix: 'xmlresults'
        }));

        var fs = require('fs-extra');

        fs.emptyDir('./target/screenshots/', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
            specDone: function (result) {
                if (result.status == 'failed') {
                    browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                        var browserName = caps.get('browserName');

                        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                            var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./target/screenshots/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName + '.png');
                            stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                            stream.end();
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    },

    //HTMLReport called once tests are finished
    onComplete: function () {
        var browserName, browserVersion;
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
            browserName = caps.get('browserName');
            browserVersion = caps.get('version');
            platform = caps.get('platform');

            var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');

            testConfig = {
                reportTitle: 'Protractor Test Execution Report',
                outputPath: './target/',
                outputFilename: 'ProtractorTestReport',
                screenshotPath: './screenshots',
                testBrowser: browserName,
                browserVersion: browserVersion,
                modifiedSuiteName: false,
                screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: true,
                testPlatform: platform
            };
            new HTMLReport().from('./target/xmlresults.xml', testConfig);
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: may be a console.log in your code somewhere?

Comment: search string `console.` cross the whole source code

Comment: attach protractor config.

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare I added any ref. to console above. This code is never executed btw

Comment: @Infern0 I added the conf.js file above. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, there was a time when Undefined was not being thrown and I still had console references in some files. I believe the issue might lie in the conf.js as that is what I have updated recently.